# pySerial list_port accuracy

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

I want to use pySerial's `serial.tools.list_ports.comports()` to list available COM ports.

Reading the [documentation](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/pyserial_api.html#serial.tools.list_ports.comports):

> The function returns an iterable that yields tuples of three strings:
>
> - port name as it can be passed to serial.Serial or serial.serial_for_url()
> - description in human readable form
> - sort of hardware ID. E.g. may contain VID:PID of USB-serial adapters.

I'm particulary interested in the third string to search for a specific USB-serial adapter with a VID:PID pair. I would like it (ideally) to work in Windows XP and later, Mac OS X, and Linux. I've tried with pySerial 2.7 in Ubuntu 13.10 and Windows 7 and works like a charm, but the docs also say:

> Also note that the reported strings are different across platforms
>   and operating systems, even for the same device.
>
> Note: Support is limited to a number of operating systems. On some
>   systems description and hardware ID will not be available.

Do you have any real-world experience with respect these ambiguities? More detailed info? Any non-working example? Variations on the hardware ID strings across systems?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: ID variation across systems, here's one, you can do `serial.Serial(0)` for arbitrary integer `0`, except that it has different meaning on windows and linux. Remember that windows numbers start with COM1 and linux from ttyS0, then add to that windows COM past 9 are `\\.\COM10`, while linux udev allows you to create arbitrary symlinks. Finally you'll end up passing exact strings to `serial.Serail()`

Comment: @qarma `serial.Serial(0)` will give you a handle on COM1 on windows 7. In general you can pass `int(COM_NUMBER - 1)' to get the right port, also for Indexes >9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been some time since my original question, but current versions of pyserial (3.0+, I believe) have solved this in a neat way. No more *clever* parsing.

[serial.tools.list_ports.comports(...)](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tools.html#serial.tools.list_ports.comports) now returns a list containing `ListPortInfo` objects.

`ListPortInfo` objects  contain `vid` and `pid` attributes (integer) as well as other useful USB-related attributes (see [docs](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tools.html#serial.tools.list_ports.ListPortInfo)) which *"are all `None` if it is not an USB device (or the platform does not support extended info)"* and this seems to be supported on the main 3 platforms (*"Under Linux, OSX and Windows, extended information will be available for USB devices"*).

So you can do something like the following:

```python
for port in serial.tools.list_ports.comports():
    if port.vid is not None and port.pid is not None:
        # It's a USB port on a platform that supports the extended info
        # Do something with it.
        print("Port={},VID={:#06x},PID={:#06x}".format(port.device, port.vid, port.pid))
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess if you want a counter-example of it working not as expected, here's what I get:

```
>>> serial.tools.list_ports.comports()
[('/dev/tty.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port', '/dev/tty.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port', '/dev/tty.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port'), ('/dev/tty.Bluetooth-Modem', '/dev/tty.Bluetooth-Modem', '/dev/tty.Bluetooth-Modem'), ('/dev/tty.usbserial-A1024XBO', '/dev/tty.usbserial-A1024XBO', '/dev/tty.usbserial-A1024XBO')]
```

where a FTDI USB-Serial adapter is plugged in. Which is expectable, because here's the `comports()` function:

```
def comports():
    """scan for available ports. return a list of device names."""
    devices = glob.glob('/dev/tty.*')
    return [(d, d, d) for d in devices]
```

which is the same for cygwin, BSD, NetBSD, IRIX, HP-UX, Solaris/SunOS, AIX…

How come that result can happen? Well, because my pyserial is version 2.6, which is only six months old :-)

After upgrading to latest version (2.7) from pypi, here's what I get:

```
>>> serial.tools.list_ports.comports()
[['/dev/cu.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port', 'n/a', 'n/a'], ['/dev/cu.Bluetooth-Modem', 'n/a', 'n/a'], ['/dev/cu.usbserial-A1024XBO', 'FT232R USB UART', 'USB VID:PID=403:6001 SNR=A1024XBO']]
```

so basically, add a version check to the latest version of `pyserial` in your setup.py, or you may get problems. Though support is still not added for other unix flavors. It looks like the `VID:PID` string is handled directly by parsing OS specific stuff to make that string generic enough. So basically I guess you can safely get it with something like : `vid, pid = sp[2].split(' ')[1].split('=')[-1].split(':')` (which is quite stupid, why parse values to build a string that has to be parsed again afterwards?!, I mean they do `szHardwareID_str = 'USB VID:PID=%s:%s SNR=%s' % (m.group(1), m.group(2), m.group(4))` we couldn't be happier with just a tuple!)

And finally, pyserial looks inconsistent with its documentation, as it says: `On some systems description and hardware ID will not be available (None).`, whereas it does really return `'n/a'`. I guess that will be fixed in pyserial 2.8 :-)

Comment: well, I'm using linux, OSX and OpenBSD on my router. I had a few FreeBSD not so long ago. And if I want to install an unix on my toaster, I'd choose netbsd :-) Though my point is that portability is not limited to Win/Mac/Linux.

Comment: I mean for the first test, the one that didn't returned the VID:PID pair, which OS was it? I know portability is more than Win/Mac/Linux but that's exactly what I need. Thanks!

Comment: it's what I said in my answer: pyserial 2.6 on OSX

Comment: I didn't see the OSX. Thanks!